# How to stop Python Pandas from converting my Object to an Int64?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `orig_df` that looks like the following:

```
            category  top_level  weekday
date            
2001-06-07  4.1       4          3
2001-10-26  4.1       4          4
2001-12-03  4.1       4          0
2001-05-31  4.4       4          3
2000-06-28  4.1       4          2
2001-05-25  4.1       4          4
2000-09-11  4.1       4          0
```

And the output of `orig_df.dtypes` is:

```
category     object
top_level    object
weekday       int32
dtype: object
```

And I want to group the data by weekday and category, so I am doing the following:

`df = orig_df.groupby(['weekday', 'category']).count().reset_index()`

which gives me the following:

```
    weekday category    top_level
0   0       4.10    23
1   0       4.11    3
2   0       4.12    3
3   0       4.13    1
4   0       4.15    2
5   0       4.16    2
6   0       4.19    1
7   0       4.20    4
8   0       4.30    2
9   0       4.40    3
10  0       4.50    3
```

the problem being that it has changed my data type of the `category` column to an `int64` when it needs to be a string, because it's a label, not a number and when it changes the label from a string to a number, it's changing things like a label of `4.1` to `4.10` which has a completely different meaning in my data set.

Here is the output of `df.dtypes`:

```
weekday        int64
category     float64
top_level      int64
dtype: object
```

How do I stop it from doing this conversion?

Comment: Can you show the output of `orig_df.dtypes`?

Comment: I have edited the original to include that output

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  If I do the groupby I get `object` as the dtype for `category`.  Can you provide a self-contained, runnable example demonstrating the problem?  (Also, what pandas version do you have?)

Comment: I can partially reproduce, not sure what is going on but I think it must relate to the indexing and un-indexing on the groupby line.  I would suggest converting 'category' to be either a string or category type.  I am wondering if you have a heterogeneous column there -- unfortunately 'object' is not as informative as we'd like there.  If so you are better off having it be of one homogeneous type, either string or categorical.  E.g. `df['category'] = df['category'].astype(str)`.  It might solve your problem and even if it doesn't, it's a good thing to do anyway